# Showing that the infimum is a minimum

Tags: real-analysis

Let $V > 0$ and let $\Phi(\cdot)$ be the standard normal CDF.

Consider the infimum of
$$f(x_1, x_2,x_3, p_1, p_2, p_3) := p_1 \Phi(x_1) + p_2 \Phi(x_2) + p_3 \Phi(x_3)$$
with respect to $x_1, x_2, x_3, p_1, p_2$ and $p_3$ satisfying

$\begin{align}
&p_1 \geq 0,\\\\
&p_2 \geq 0,\\\\
&p_3 \geq 0,\\\\
&p_1 + p_2 + p_3 = 1,\\\\
&p_1 x_1 + p_2 x_2 + p_3 x_3 = 0,\\\\
&p_1 x_1^2 + p_2 x_2^2 + p_3 x_3^2 \leq V. 
\end{align}
$

The objective is a continuous function and the feasible set is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^6$. One way to show that the infimum is a minimum is to show that the feasible set is compact. But even with the constraint $p_1 x_1^2 + p_2 x_2^2 + p_3 x_3^2 \leq V$, it can happen that $p_1$ is arbitrarily small and $x_1$ is arbitrarily large.

I think I need to use the fact that the objective function is bounded between $0$ and $1$, which together with the last constraint limits  $x_i$'s becoming very large.

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Comment: Thank you for your response. When you are passing to convergent subsequences, is that a consequence of Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem for extended reals? I have only heard of the theorem for a bounded subset of reals so getting a convergent subsequence for $(p_1^n, p_2^n, p_3^n)$ makes sense but how do you get a convergent subsequence for $(x_1^n, x_2^n, x_3^n)$?

Comment: There a number of ways to see that any sequence in $\mathbb R$ has a subsequence converging to a point in $[-\infty,\infty]$. One is as follows: If the sequence is bounded from above and from below, use the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem. If the sequence is not bounded from above, then it has a subsequence converging to $\infty$. If the sequence is not bounded from below, then it has a subsequence converging to $-\infty$. So, in each of the three cases, the sequence has a subsequence converging to a point in $[-\infty,\infty]$. Are any other details needed?

Comment: Yes, when you say for each $j \in J^c$, we have $p_j^* = 0$ and $p_j^n x_j^n \to 0$, how does $p_j^n x_j^n \to 0$ follow? Like what if $p_j^n \sim 1/n$ and $x_j^n \sim n^2$ ?

Comment: We have $p_j^n (x_j^n)^2\le V$ for all $j$ and $|x_j^n|\to\infty$ for $j\in J^c$. So, for $j\in J^c$ we have $|p_j^n x_j^n|=\dfrac{p_j^n (x_j^n)^2}{|x_j^n|}\le \dfrac V{|x_j^n|}\to0$. So, $p_j^n x_j^n\to0$ for $j\in J^c$. Are any other details needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\tx}{\tilde x}$Indeed, the infimum (say $f^*$) in question is attained for each $V\in(0,\infty)$.

To prove this, for each $j\in\{1,2,3\}$ let $(x_j^n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and $(p_j^n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be sequences such that for each $n$ all your conditions are satisfied with $x_1^n,x_2^n,x_3^n,p_1^n,p_2^n,p_3^n$ in place of $x_1,x_2,x_3,p_1,p_2,p_3$ and
\begin{equation}
    f(x_1^n,x_2^n,x_3^n,p_1^n,p_2^n,p_3^n)\to f^*
\end{equation}
(as $n\to\infty$). Passing to subsequences, without loss of generality assume that for each $j\in\{1,2,3\}$
\begin{equation}
x_j^n\to x_j^*\in[-\infty,\infty],\quad p_j^n\to p_j^*\in[0,1]. 
\end{equation}
Let
\begin{equation}
    J:=\{j\in\{1,2,3\}\colon x_j^*\in\R\},\quad J^c:=\{1,2,3\}\setminus J.  
\end{equation}
Since $p_j^n (x_j^n)^2\le V<\infty$, we see that for each $j\in J^c$ we have $p_j^*=0$ and $p_j^n x_j^n\to0$. So, letting $\tx_j:=x_j^*\,1(j\in J)$ for  $j\in\{1,2,3\}$, we have
\begin{equation}
    p_j^*\ge0\ \forall j\in\{1,2,3\},\quad \sum_{j=1}^3 p_j^*=1, 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{j=1}^3 p_j^*\tx_j=\sum_{j\in J} p_j^*x_j^*=\lim_n \sum_{j=1}^3 p_j^n x_j^n=\lim_n 0=0, 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{j=1}^3 p_j^*\tx_j^2=\sum_{j\in J} p_j^*(x_j^*)^2=\lim_n \sum_{j\in J}p_j^n (x_j^n)^2
    \le\limsup_n \sum_{j=1}^3 p_j^n (x_j^n)^2\le V,  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{j=1}^3 p_j^*\Phi(\tx_j)=\sum_{j\in J} p_j^*\Phi(x_j^*)
    =\lim_n \sum_{j\in J} p_j^n \Phi(x_j^n)
    =\lim_n \sum_{j=1}^3 p_j^n \Phi(x_j^n)=f^*.  
\end{equation}

So, all your conditions are satisfied with $\tx_1,\tx_2,\tx_3,p_1^*,p_2^*,p_3^*$ in place of $x_1,x_2,x_3,p_1,p_2,p_3$ and
the infimum $f^*$ is attained at $(x_1,x_2,x_3,p_1,p_2,p_3)=(\tx_1,\tx_2,\tx_3,p_1^*,p_2^*,p_3^*)$.
$\quad\Box$